# The client.Height function in conjunction with the forEach method JS

Tags: javascript

I have an accordion list and my task was to implement a smooth tabs open/close function for dynamic content without a set height.
The forEach method works perfectly.

The smooth open/close function (setHeight in JS snippet)also works fine, but only for the first tab.

In other tabs this function does not work and the opening does not happen as we would like it to.
I've already racked my brains.
How can I combine the forEach method and the "setHeight" function so that nothing breaks?

```js
const accItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

accItems.forEach((item) => {
  const icon = item.querySelector('.accordion__icon');
  const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');

    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (item.classList.contains('open')) {
        item.classList.remove('open');
        icon.classList.remove('open');
        content.classList.remove('open');
    
        } else {
        const accOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
        accOpen.forEach((open) => {
        open.classList.remove('open');
        });

        item.classList.add('open');
        icon.classList.add('open');
        content.classList.add('open');
        }
        
        if (content.clientHeight) {
            content.style.height = 0;
        }   else {
            let accText = item.querySelector('.acc-text');
            content.style.height = accText.clientHeight + "px";
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  background: #f2f2f2; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

h5 {
  margin: 0; }

p {
  margin: 0; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 140rem; }

.section-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 134rem;
  margin: auto; }

.accordion-image {
  width: 630px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url("https://eternel.maitreart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/creat-home-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }

.accordion {
  width: 63rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 8rem; }
  .accordion__item {
    border-top: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s;
    padding-bottom: 1rem; }
    .accordion__item:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a6a4; }
    .accordion__item--header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
      cursor: pointer; }
    .accordion__item.open {
      width: 100%; }
  .accordion__title {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .accordion__icon {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    transition: transform .5s ease; }
    .accordion__icon span:first-child {
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(1px);
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor; }
    .accordion__icon span {
      display: block;
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor;
      cursor: pointer; }
    .accordion__icon.open {
      transform: rotate(45deg); }
  .accordion__content {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.62;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    height: 0;
    transition: height .5s;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .accordion__content.open {
      margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
      height: 100%; }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <section class="section-accordion">
            <div class="accordion-image"></div>
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__item open">
                        <div class="accordion__item--header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Visual direction</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon open">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content open">
                            <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__item--header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Event production</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
                                <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__item--header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Brand creation</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
                                <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__item--header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Design concept</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
                                <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `id`s within the document must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

cleaned up js to make it more readable:

```
const accItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item'); 
function handleItemClick(e, i) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();

    const actives = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
    while (actives.length)
        actives[0].classList.remove('open');
    accItems[i].classList.add("open"); 
}
accItems.forEach((item, i) => 
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => handleItemClick(e, i))
);
```

Handling height with just css:

I made icon and content children of .open

```
 .accordion {
    width: 63rem;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 8rem; }
    .accordion__item {
        border-top: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: height .5s;
        padding-bottom: 1rem; }
        .accordion__item:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a6a4; }
        .accordion__item--header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
        cursor: pointer; }
        .open .accordion__item {
        width: 100%; }
    .accordion__title {
        font-family: 'Lora';
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        line-height: 1.2;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase; }
    .accordion__icon {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 0;
        transition: transform .5s ease; }
        .accordion__icon span:first-child {
        transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(1px);
        width: 1.4rem;
        height: .1rem;
        background: currentColor; }
        .accordion__icon span {
        display: block;
        width: 1.4rem;
        height: .1rem;
        background: currentColor;
        cursor: pointer; }
        open .accordion__icon {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        height: 2rem; }
    .accordion__content {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        line-height: 1.62;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
        height: 0;
        transition: height .5s;
        overflow: hidden; }
        .open .accordion__content {
        margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
        height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Why do you think there might be a conflict of if/else conditions?
When you click on an inactive tab, the active tab is not closed.
I updated the JS code.
Can you please see what the error could be?

Comment: @Paffly I updated your loop so it removes all opens and only adds it to what is clicked... i believe.

Comment: When you click on the active tab, it is deleted.
But the "add" class is no longer added to any tab:)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'). So it says "event" - undefined.

Comment: @Paffly i acidentall forgot to put "open" in one of the classlist.adds.  Are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes, the console is still swearing that there is an error from this place:
e.target.classlist.add('open')

Comment: @Paffly I had a typo classlist to classList.  Help me out here, I'm being lazy :-)

Comment: I corrected that:) Now this is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (app.js:64:14)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242688/discussion-between-joe-fitzsimmons-and-paffly).

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you need setHeight which is the one that messes the display

Here is a delegated version

```js
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item");
document.querySelector('.accordion').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const item = e.target.closest(".accordion__item");
  if (!item) return
  accordionItems.forEach(acItem => {
    if (acItem !== item) {
      acItem.classList.remove('open');
      acItem.querySelector('.accordion__icon').classList.remove('open');
      acItem.querySelector('.accordion__content').classList.remove('open');
    }
  });
  
  const icon = item.querySelector('.accordion__icon');
  const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');
  item.classList.toggle("open")
  const isOpen = item.classList.contains("open");
  icon.classList.toggle("open", isOpen);
  content.classList.toggle('open', isOpen);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 140rem;
}

.section-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 134rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.accordion-image {
  width: 630px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url("https://eternel.maitreart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/creat-home-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.accordion {
  width: 63rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 8rem;
}

.accordion__item {
  border-top: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .5s;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.accordion__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
}

.accordion__item--header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion__item.open {
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion__title {
  font-family: 'Lora';
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.accordion__icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.accordion__icon span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(1px);
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: .1rem;
  background: currentColor;
}

.accordion__icon span {
  display: block;
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: .1rem;
  background: currentColor;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion__icon.open {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion__content {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.62;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  height: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion__content.open {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="section-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-image"></div>
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion__item open">
        <div class="accordion__item--header">
          <h5 class="accordion__title">Visual direction</h5>
          <div class="accordion__icon open">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content open" id="content__wrapper">
          <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__item">
        <div class="accordion__item--header">
          <h5 class="accordion__title">Event production</h5>
          <div class="accordion__icon">
            <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
            <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content" id="content__wrapper">
          <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__item">
        <div class="accordion__item--header">
          <h5 class="accordion__title">Brand creation</h5>
          <div class="accordion__icon">
            <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
            <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content" id="content__wrapper">
          <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__item">
        <div class="accordion__item--header">
          <h5 class="accordion__title">Design concept</h5>
          <div class="accordion__icon">
            <span class="accordion__icon--first"></span>
            <span class="accordion__icon--second"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content" id="content__wrapper">
          <p class="acc-text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```